# How to assign textvariable to different variable names within a loop - Python - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Code:

```
for i in range(len(self.models_chosen)):
    self.test.insert(i, vars())
    self.model_entry_dict_text["entry" + str(i)] = ttk.Label(
        self.entry_frame,
        text="Quantity of: " + self.models_chosen[i]
    )
    self.model_entry_dict_text["entry" + str(i)].pack(fill=X)
    self.model_entry_dict["entry" + str(i)] = Spinbox(self.entry_frame, from_=0, to=2000,)
    self.model_entry_dict["entry" + str(i)].pack(fill=X)
    self.models_entry_box_created = True
    self.old_models = self.models_chosen
```

What I have done is made a dictionary within a `for in range` called -

```
self.model_entry_dict["entry" + str(i)]
```

So it would be:

```
self.model_entry_dict["entry1"] = Spinbox(self..) 
self.model_entry_dict["entry2"] = Spinbox(self..)
self.model_entry_dict["entry3"] = Spinbox(self..)
```

...

depending on the range.

For each of the `spinboxes` that I have created, I need the value from inside them (which is why I have put the text variable option as part of the arguments) - The problem is I don't know how to have a different variable for each `spinbox` created due to the `spinboxes` being created in a loop.

Say I put `self.textvariable`, all the `spinboxes` would have the same value. An example of what I want to have would be

```
textvariable = self.variable+i
```

so:

```
self.variable1 to be the text variable for self.model_entry_dict["entry1"]  
self.variable2 to be the text variable for self.model_entry_dict["entry2"]
... etc.
```

To which I then just do:

`self.variable1.get()` - And it should get the number that is inside the `spinbox`

But I don't think it's possible to add a string/integer to a variable name.

Here you can see an image of the models I have chosen in the listbox, I then pressed update button and it generated 3 spinboxes, now I want to retrieve the numbers in the spinboxes (whether it be stored into 3 different variables or in a list/dictionary/array):

http://gyazo.com/a7c9847ec16b16fb443082066b42f890

example of what I'm looking for is (using the image provided above):

```
test1 = self.variable1.get()
print(test1)

    output:
        1800
test2 = self.variable2.get()
print(test2)

    output:
        300
test3 = self.variable3.get()
print(test3)

    output:
        30
```

I'm sorry if this may seem a little confusing, I started using Python for a week or so, so it's probably sloppy. I'm sure there's probably better ways of doing this and different methods.

Comment: Look up lists in the doc, they should do what you need. It'd basically instead be like `self.variable[n]`

Comment: I've tried, but you can't use get() within lists.

Comment: Is that a specific characteristic of tkinter? Regular Python has no issue with you calling methods on an element of a list.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to give each variable a name. Just use a list:

```
self.vars = []
for i in range(len(self.models_chosen)):
    var = StringVar()
    self.vars.append(var)
    ...
    self.model_entry_dict["entry" + str(i)].config(textvariable=var)
```